# Send an Image with an HttpResponse ActixWeb

Tags: rust, actix-web

i try to send an image with an HttpResponse with actix web
my response looks like this
my problem is that i can just return an static u8 but buffer is a [u8; 4096] and not static is there any way to make it possible to send an image?

```rust
 HttpResponse::Ok()
           .content_type("image/jpeg")
           .body(buffer)
```

buffer is:

```
let mut f = fs::File::open(x).expect("Somthing went wrong");
let mut buffer = [0;4096];
let n = f.read(&mut buffer[..]);
```

The full func:

```
fn img_response(x: PathBuf, y: Image)->HttpResponse{
    let mut f = fs::File::open(x).expect("Somthing went wrong");
    let mut buffer = [0;4096];
    let n = f.read(&mut buffer[..]);
    match y{
        Image::JPG =>{ 
            HttpResponse::Ok()
            .content_type("image/jpeg")
            .body(buffer)}
        Image::PNG =>{ 
            HttpResponse::Ok()
            .content_type("image/png")
            .body(buffer)}
        Image::ICO => {
            HttpResponse::Ok()
            .content_type("image/x-icon")
            .body(buffer)}
        }   
}
```

The func img_response get called in my index func

```
 match path.extension().unwrap().to_str().unwrap(){
"png" => {return img_response(path, Image::PNG);}
"jpeg" => {return img_response(path, Image::JPG);}
"ico" => {return img_response(path, Image::ICO);}
};
```

full code: https://github.com/Benn1x/Kiwi
The Code Compressed:

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

use actix_web::{ web, App, HttpRequest,HttpResponse , HttpServer};
use mime;
use std::path::PathBuf;
use serde_derive::Deserialize;
use std::process::exit;
use toml;
use std::fs::read_to_string;
use actix_web::http::header::ContentType;
use std::fs;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io;

fn img_response(x: PathBuf)->HttpResponse{
    let mut f = fs::File::open(x).expect("Somthing went wrong");
    let mut buffer = [0;4096];
    let n = f.read(&mut buffer[..]); 
    HttpResponse::Ok()
    .content_type("image/jpeg")
    .body(buffer)
}
async fn index(req: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse {
let mut path: PathBuf = req.match_info().query("file").parse().unwrap();
match path.extension().unwrap().to_str().unwrap(){
            "jpeg" => {return img_response(path);}
            _ => {return img_response(path);}
            }   
}
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .route("/{file:.*}", web::get().to(index))
            .service(actix_files::Files::new("/", ".").index_file("index.html"))
        })  
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

This is the The main.rs but just with the func that returns an image

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that showcases what you have done; including a `main()` function so that we can just copy-paste your code. Then describe what you are trying to achieve, and what your code is currently doing. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information about how to ask a question.

Comment: @Finomnis now better?

Comment: Better, but not there yet. I can't copy-paste this anywhere. A `main()` is missing. I acknowledge that you posted a link to your github, but links to code is considered non-permanent and against the policies of Stackoverflow.
Please reduce your code down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please actually read this link and all the points written in it. The goal is to reduce your code to the absolute minimum required to reproduce your problem. In most cases you find by yourself what the problem is in the process.

Comment: Try to reduce the code in your github down to a minimal example, and then paste that example here as code. Including a `main()` and everything, so we can copy-paste it into a `main.rs` file, run it and get the same result that you get.

Comment: @Finomnis now its just the image func and the `main()`

Comment: Now all that's missing for a proper question is an actual question :) You say *"i try to send"* - What problems did you run into? What specific questions do you have? What do you expect to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: @Finomnis as i said io try to return an Image but the u8 in whot i format the file is not an static on is there an other way to format the image so i can send it?

Comment: Additional comment: You ignore the return value of `f.read()`. You usually need to see how big the read data actually was and then create a slice of that buffer with the actual size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`HttpResponse::Ok()`](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/struct.HttpResponse.html#method.Ok) returns a [`HttpResponseBuilder`](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/struct.HttpResponseBuilder.html).
Its method [`.body()`](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/struct.HttpResponseBuilder.html#method.body) takes a generic argument that has to implement the [`MessageBody`](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/body/trait.MessageBody.html) trait.

Now here is your problem: `[u8; 4096]` does **not** implement `MessageBody`. What **does**, however, [implement `MessageBody`, is `Vec<u8>`](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/body/trait.MessageBody.html#impl-MessageBody-for-Vec%3Cu8%2C%20Global%3E).

Therefore by modifying your static array to a dynamic vector, your code seems to compile:

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

use actix_web::{web, App, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpServer};
use std::fs;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn img_response(x: PathBuf) -> HttpResponse {
    let mut f = fs::File::open(x).expect("Somthing went wrong");
    let mut buffer = vec![0; 4096];
    let n = f.read(&mut buffer[..]);
    HttpResponse::Ok().content_type("image/jpeg").body(buffer)
}
async fn index(req: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse {
    let mut path: PathBuf = req.match_info().query("file").parse().unwrap();
    match path.extension().unwrap().to_str().unwrap() {
        "jpeg" => {
            return img_response(path);
        }
        _ => {
            return img_response(path);
        }
    }
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .route("/{file:.*}", web::get().to(index))
            .service(actix_files::Files::new("/", ".").index_file("index.html"))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

---

There are still problems with your code, though:

- The buffer doesn't get sliced to the correct size
- Images larger than the buffer get cut down to the first 4096 bytes

Here is a working version of your code:

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

use actix_web::{web, App, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpServer};
use std::fs;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn img_response(x: PathBuf) -> HttpResponse {
    let mut f = fs::File::open(x).expect("Somthing went wrong");
    let mut image_data = vec![];
    let mut buffer = [0; 4096];

    loop {
        let n = f.read(&mut buffer[..]).unwrap();
        if n == 0 {
            break;
        }
        image_data.extend_from_slice(&buffer[..n]);
    }

    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type("image/jpeg")
        .body(image_data)
}
async fn index(req: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse {
    let path: PathBuf = req.match_info().query("file").parse().unwrap();
    match path.extension().unwrap().to_str().unwrap() {
        "jpeg" => {
            return img_response(path);
        }
        _ => {
            return img_response(path);
        }
    }
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .route("/{file:.*}", web::get().to(index))
            .service(actix_files::Files::new("/", ".").index_file("index.html"))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Note that for large image sizes, it would be benefitial to use the [`.streaming()`](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/struct.HttpResponseBuilder.html#method.streaming) body instead:

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

use actix_web::{web, App, Error, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpServer};
use async_stream::{try_stream, AsyncStream};
use bytes::Bytes;
use std::fs;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn img_response(x: PathBuf) -> HttpResponse {
    let stream: AsyncStream<Result<Bytes, Error>, _> = try_stream! {
        let mut f = fs::File::open(x)?;
        let mut buffer = [0; 4096];
        loop{
            let n = f.read(&mut buffer[..])?;
            if n == 0 {
                break;
            }
            yield Bytes::copy_from_slice(&buffer[..n]);
        }
    };

    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type("image/jpeg")
        .streaming(stream)
}

async fn index(req: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse {
    let path: PathBuf = req.match_info().query("file").parse().unwrap();
    match path.extension().unwrap().to_str().unwrap() {
        "jpeg" => {
            return img_response(path);
        }
        _ => {
            return img_response(path);
        }
    }
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .route("/{file:.*}", web::get().to(index))
            .service(actix_files::Files::new("/", ".").index_file("index.html"))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Comment: oh sh*ti totally forgot to try vectors , thx the code works fine and does what needs to do

Comment: @Benn1x Added info about some more problems I found. Although you probably already realized them.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to:

```rust
fn img_response(x: PathBuf) -> HttpResponse {
    let stream: AsyncStream<Result<Bytes, Error>, _> = try_stream! {
        let mut f = fs::File::open(x)?;
        let mut buffer = [0; 4096];
        loop{
            let n = f.read(&mut buffer[..])?;
            if n == 0 {
                break;
            }
            yield Bytes::copy_from_slice(&buffer[..n]);
        }
    };

    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type("image/jpeg")
        .streaming(stream)
}
```

You could do something like (also streams the file):

```rust
async fn img_response(x: PathBuf) -> HttpResponse {
    let file = actix_files::NamedFile::open_async(x).await.unwrap();
    file.into_response()
}
```

https://github.com/actix/actix-web/discussions/2720#discussioncomment-2510752